# Spring security does not redirect to home page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, apache-tiles

Hi I am facing a problem with redirecting my requests to the home page when I type the url of the base servlet.

When I type

http://localhost:8080/servlet/home

This works fine but when I type

http://localhost:8080/servlet/

I would like to see the home page whereas the system redirect it to the access denied page.

Controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectHome() {
    return "home";
}
```

Spring security

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
<intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />  
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />   
...
```

Comment: Have u put welcome file in web.xml?

Comment: I did not check that and apparently it is the issue

Comment: @PrasannaKumarHA thanks a lot. Please post your answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your web.xml file for welcome file.

```
     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>[your page]</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```